# JQuery / ES6 Events - Waiting the end of a custom event triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm not sure it's a/the good approach so feel free to tell me if it's a bad idea from the beginning, but here I go :

I cut a front page in 3 scripts:

- One checking the permission
- One loading the data
- One custom printing stuff depending what happened before

All is working well except: I would like to call several routes to load data, and I need to wait for all the loading to end before the custom printing!

I have something like that to summarize the idea

```
on('loadData') {
    // Might be in several scripts on the page, for the different routes to call
}

checkAccess {

   // Checking the user can access

   trigger('loadData');
   // Some... waiting I can't find
   customPrint();

}
```

I need to call the `customPrint` once I'm 100% sure all the `loadData` triggered are done loading.

I would like to avoid putting weird intervals and loopchecking.
Worst case scenario I can do `Promise.all()`, but I would have to name the Promises, the idea of just triggering the event and stack the routes I want to call in the future seduces me !

Is there anyway to check/wait if all the events triggered by `loadData` are done?

Thanks !
Best regards

Comment: promises are the best solution (and you probably don't need promise.all), or you can pass customPrint to trigger as second parameter and call it at the end.

Comment: The trigger as second parameter will be an issue if it's received by multiple 'on' right ?
I will probably end up using Promises ended, I'll use namespace to go through all and call them to avoid having to edit the first script each time I need/want a new one.